# delete n lines between 2 matching patterns, keeing the first match and deleting the second match

Tags: regex, bash, sed, awk

Given data in a text file:

```
string1 EP00 37.45 83.83 
save
save
save
gibberish
gibberish
gibberish
gibberish
gibberish
gibberish
gibberish
gibberish
gibberish
gibberish
gibberish
gibberish
gibberish
string2

gibberish
gibberish
gibberish
gibberish
gibberish
gibberish
gibberish
gibberish
gibberish
gibberish
gibberish
gibberish
gibberish
```

I would like to use `sed` or `awk` to match both string1 and string 2, then delete everything after `string1` and the first 3 lines. I would like to it to also delete `string2`, but not `string1`. And also delete one extra line in between that and the next text. So the expected output would be:

```
string1 EP00 37.45 83.83 
save
save
save
```

There are always the same number of lines in between the two patterns if that helps (16). I would like to do this with `sed` or `awk`, but have only been able to figure out a script to delete the entire block of data between the two, holding onto both strings:

```
sed '/string1/,/string2/{//!d}' file >> tr.txt
```

Does anyone know how to specify to retain `string1` and the three lines after it and delete the rest of the lines in between the two patterns including `string2`? I would like to do this with `sed` or `awk`, whichever is easier.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this awk:

```
awk '/^string1/{i=0} /^string1/,/^string2/{i++; if (i<5) print; next}1' file
string1 EP00 37.45 83.83 
save
save
save
```

Comment: This one seems to do it for all blocks of text, not just those that contain string1 and string2--is there a way to change this?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be doing anything to the text file to delete the contents anymore

Comment: Ignore my other comment, it actually works now for only string1 blockettes but only retains the first string1 and the three lines after for the first instance of string1...could there be an adaptation to retain it for all blocks?

Comment: Awesome that works fantastically! Thank you so much :) I was missing the declaration of i=0. If there were a trailing space between the text deleted between the two patterns and the next text, is there a way to delete it in this same awk command?

Comment: It is still a single awk command. I didn't understand trailing space question. You mean there are blank lines after `string2`?

Comment: Yes sorry, I understand the above is one awk command. What I meant is that there is a blank line in between the saved text, i.e., string1 and the three lines kept, and the text below it. Is there a way to delete that blank line so the text doesn't have a line in between it? I meant to ask if there is a way to do it in the same awk command above

Comment: I can do it with a second command, the awk command I provided in my original question but was wondering if there was a better/more efficient way to do it once we run through the file and are making the edits

Comment: I am on mobile now so unable to test but you can try this: `awk '/^string1/{i=0} /^string1/,/^string2/{i++; if (i<5) {if ($0=="") i--; else print; }next}1' file`

Comment: Lovely solution, but takes some careful reading - not for beginners! Might I suggest that you update your "final" answer with the most recent edit?

Comment: Oh OK I will test it as soon as I reach back to my computer. Meanwhile can you provide a sample of this input with spaces in your question so that I can understand it better and provide you best possible answer.

Comment: anubhava, yes I have updated my answer to show the space in between the next text. Essentially I am using this call to get rid of some unwanted text in between two patterns.

Comment: Essentially I would like the space between string2 and gibberish to be removed after everything is deleted in between the two patterns (everything but the lines we are saving)

Comment: OK thanks for your edit. I am traveling today and posting this comment from my mobile. I will test this new input tomorrow once I get back to my computer and edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: One clarification. Do you want to delete blank lines just after string2 only or any where in the file?

Comment: @user1332577: Just came back to my computer. Try this command: **`awk '/^string1/{i=0} /^string1/,/^string2/{a=1; i++; if (i<5) print; next} a && /^$/{next} {a=0} 1' file`**

Comment: That seemed to do the trick! Thanks so much anubhava, I appreciate your persistence in helping to solve the problem :)

Comment: I realized after processing a few files that the above string seems to delete all the lines I want including 'string2' for all of the entries but the last one. On the last pattern match it retains string2--why is it doing that?

Comment: I will be able to answer that if you provide me a sample input file for which it is misbehaving. Edit you question and provide a sample of those files where you are seeing this behavior.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do this with `awk`, the script might look something like this (updated based on your comments; it now "recycles", so it will do the matching correctly for as many times as you have the string1-string2 pattern. I realize you have already got an answer you accepted but wanted to give you this alternative; it is much less "professional" than @anubhava's answer, but it might give you an insight in how to make `awk` do "anything you want", even if you are not a pro):

```
BEGIN {
  state = 0;
  }
{ if($1 == "string1") {
     state = 1;
   }
   if (state == 1) {
      state = 2;
      print;
      next;
   }
   if (state > 1 && state < 5) {
       print;
       state = state + 1;
       next;
   }
   if ($1 == "string2") {
       state = 6;
       next;
   }
   if (state == 6) {
       state = 0;
       next;
   }
   if (state == 0) {
       print;
       next;
   }
}
```

The `state` variable basically tells you "where am I in the logic".  The states are:

```
0: "normal state", print the line, go to the next
1: "found string2", start printing this line and the next three
2 - 4: printing "the lines that followed string1"
5: Waiting for string2, not printing anything
6: found string2, need to delete the next line
   Having found the next line, we reset the state to 0 again…
```

You would run it with

```
awk -f scriptFile.awk inputfile.txt > outputfile.txt
```

I made this "pedestrian", so you can see exactly what is done, and in what order. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: It looks like this one only does it for the first entry, and actually gets rid of the first string and the next 3 lines. Is there a way it could do it for all the text blocks that contain string 1 (there are more than one) and retain the first string and the three lines after it? It seems to output the second block I want and gets rid of everything I want except for retaining string1 and the next three lines

Comment: For my comment "And also delete.." there's a space between the two matched patterns and the next text in the file that I would like to get rid of. Can this script be adapted to cycle through all of the instances of string1?

Comment: This is great Floris, thank you for the lesson! I really appreciate the opportunity to learn more about awk, it's something I'm trying to learn how to implement to it's fullest potential :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
sed -e '1,/^string1/-1d' -e '/string1/+4,$/d' < file > output
```

The first command removed from line 1 up to the line preceeding a line starting with "string1", and the second finds the line starting with "string1", counts 4 lines after that, and deletes from there to the end.

You could also do this, if your version of `grep` supports it:

```
grep -A3 "^string1" file > output
```

Comment: When I use the sed command you provided above I get the following error: sed: -e expression #1, char 10: unknown command: `-' ? The grep -A3 example you gave would grab them out but I need to cycle through all instances of these string1. What I'm trying to do is delete between the matching patterns but there's text below, so I'm deleting a subset of text that I don't need.

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU sed

```
sed -n '/^string1/,+3p' file
```

If no GNU sed, try this:

```
sed  -n ':a;/string1/{N;N;N;p;ta;}' file
```

Comment: This solution doesn't take into account that deleted lines are between both patterns.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -rn '/string1/{h;d};H;/string2/{x;s/(string1([^\n]*\n){4}).*string2.*/\1/p}' file
```